# CPLEX give me this error " V23 has never been used"

Tags: constraints, cplex

A part of input is:

```
  tuple copie_macchine {

      int macchina;

      int copia1;

      int copia2;

      int copia3; 

   }

   {copie_macchine} copie = ...;

   int macc [I1][J] = ...;

   {int} s = {1,2,4,5,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};

   macc = [[1, 10],
    [1, 1],
    [3, 3],
    [0, 4]];

    copie = {<3,3,4,0>,
     <6,7,8,9>,
     <8,11,12,0>,
     <9,13,14,0>,
     <10,15,16,0>,
     <20,26,27,28>};

     dvar boolean y[I][J][M];
```

and I write in Cplex this code: the algorithm assigns to the variable y 1 if the value macc [i] [j] is in the set s otherwise it must choose to assign the value 1 either to copy 1 or to copy 2 or to copy

```
forall (j in J)

forall (i in I1 : macc [i][j] in  s)
  
  forall (i1 in I : i1==i)
  
    forall (m in M)
        
 V22:  y[i1][j][m] == 1;


  forall (j in J)
    
    forall (c in copie : c.copia3!=0)
    
     forall (i in I1 : macc[i][j] == c.macchina)
                   
             forall (i1 in I : i1==i)
       
                 forall (m in M)
       
   V23:  y[i1][j][c.copia1] == 1 ||  y[i1][j][c.copia2] == 1 ||  y[i1][j][c.copia3] == 1;
```

but I have the error "V23 has never been used". How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your line that contains V23 is never used.

Let me share a smaller example which replicates this warning:

```
dvar int+ x;

subject to
{
  x<=10;
  forall(i in 1..2:i>=5)
    
    {
      
       ct:(x==2) ;
   }  
}
```

gives

```
ct has never been used
```

Comment: Just to clarify why you are getting that error in your code. You need to add braces {} around multiple statements that you want to use inside a loop. You may have previous experience using Python where the scope of things like loops is defined by the indentation. Most other programming languages use braces or similar to indicate blocks of statements.